# How can I make a UIButton within PinView open a pop up view?

Tags: ios, uibutton

Hello so I am working on this app so I can press a button within the PinView and it will load a pop up view. I am very confused as to how to get this working because I would think I need to have it as an IBAction but I don't think I can do that because it's hidden from the main.storyboard.

```
extension ViewController : MKMapViewDelegate {
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView?{
    if annotation is MKUserLocation {
        //return nil so map view draws "blue dot" for standard user location
        return nil
    }
    let reuseId = "pin"
    var pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reuseId) as? MKPinAnnotationView
    pinView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
    pinView?.pinTintColor = UIColor(red: 52/255.0, green: 73/255.0, blue: 94/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    pinView?.canShowCallout = true
    let removeButton = UIButton(type: .Custom)
    removeButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40)
    removeButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "RadiusSettings")!, forState: .Normal)
    pinView?.leftCalloutAccessoryView = removeButton
    return pinView
    }
}
```

[This is my main.storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0iid.png)

Any help would be appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the map view's `delegate`, implement [`calloutAccessoryControlTapped`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/MKMapViewDelegate/mapView:annotationView:calloutAccessoryControlTapped:).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can easily put a button in the annotation view, but as Matt alludes to in his answer, you can add a button to the callout view that's shown when the user taps on the annotation view.

The user would need to tap on the annotation view, (usually a pin) which shows the callout view, including a button if you've added one. The user then taps the button on the callout and your `calloutAccessoryControlTapped` method gets called.